# Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'getDownloadURL' Swift and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve the url for an image from firebase storage.

I want to get the URL so I can pass to an image processing API.

I get the following error "Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'getDownloadURL'"

Can't seem to find anything online.

Thanks for help!

```
@IBAction func pullImageTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let ref = storageRef.child(imageName)
    imageDownloaded.sd_setImage(with: ref)
    var referenceURL = storageRef.child(imageName).getDownloadURL() //Error here 
    print(imageURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called `downloadURL`. See the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#downloadurlcompletion:) and the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url). The latter even has this handy example:

> ```
> // Create a reference to the file you want to download
> let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
>
> // Fetch the download URL
> starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
>   if let error = error {
>     // Handle any errors
>   } else {
>     // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How exactly do I pull the URL? I entered this and it yields () in console

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let ref = storageRef.child(imageName)
        imageDownloaded.sd_setImage(with: ref)
        let refURL = ref.downloadURL { url, error in
          if let error = error {
          } else {
          }
        }
        print(refURL)

I am a beginner thanks for your patience

Comment: The print needs to be inside the closure, where the `// Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'` comment is. You can't use it outside of that closure. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437031/problem-with-firestore-database-and-storage/61442896#61442896